# User Controls required an ID in postback?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I add some div into a panel on server side, when the page is generated, and I add a ID for each one :

```
HtmlGenericControl divContainerInside = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divContainerInside.ID = "inside_" + m_oIDCategoria + "_" + numero;
```

than, on postback (after re-creating them), I cycle them :

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl divInside in myPanel.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{
    Response.Write(divInside.ID);
}
```

all is ok! But, if I remove that `divContainerInside.ID` when I generate it, I get a NullException cycling them. Why?

Comment: where do you get the NullException? when you call Response.Write or before that?

Comment: Yes, when I call Response.Write! If I wrote `if(divInside!=null) Response.Write(divInside.ID);` no exception, but of course no Output...

Comment: I think it's normal... if you don't set the ID when you create the element than you don't have the id when retrieve the element...

Comment: Well...but not just the ID. I mean, the `divInside` itself is null :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you get NullException when you try to read the ID, which you haven't set.

If you change your code like this, you'll get the value:

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl divInside in myPanel.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{
    Response.Write(divInside.ClientID);
}
```

PS: I don't know if you have got this line of code:

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(divContainerInside);
```

If you want to find out more about web controls you can read this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx) and [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/ASP_NET/re-113573_The_difference_between_ID_ClientID_and_UniqueID.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You cant add a control to the page using response.Write you need to add it to the Pages or another controls control collection like below:

```
Page.Controls.Add(divInside);
```